# How to get the active_id of one2many in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In the below method `complete_operation` I used to print active id, but it display `None`. I want to display current id of `mrp.production`. `mrp.operations` is one2many field of `mrp.production`.

```py
class mrpProduction(models.Model):
    _inherit = "mrp.production"

    end_date = fields.Datetime('Scheduled End Date') 
    operations = fields.One2many('mrp.operations','operation_id', 'Operations')  


class mrpOperations(models.Model):
    _name = "mrp.operations"

    name = fields.Many2one("custom.operations", "Operation Name")
    status = fields.Selection([('Completed','Completed'),('Pending','Pending')],'Status')
    operation_id = fields.Integer()

    @api.multi
    def complete_operation(self):  
        print self.id
        active_id=self.env.context.get('active_id')
        print active_id,'--'
```

Comment: `operation_id` should be a `Many2one` to `mrp.production`. And what is `complete_operation()` for? Since there is a one2many relation between productions and operations, you could just print/return `self.operation_id.id` (assuming you changed it to `Many2one`).

Comment: @Mani Active Id you will only if you are wotking with wizard object

Answer (score 0):

here **operation_id** which can hold the current id of mrp.production if you **change the operation_id as a many2one model of mrp.production**

Answer (score 0):

There's also a variable called active_ids in the context.
active_id is actually active_ids[0].

```
        active_ids=self.env.context.get('active_ids')
```